# Display text changes like Bitbucket

Tags: php, symfony, bitbucket

is there a php tool, or something to format text just like Bitbucket does on a pull request? I want to do a versioning system for some entities in Symfony2 and I need to make a page with all the changes that were made on all the fields within that entity, and display them just like Bitbucket does.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So you want a diff tool for PHP? Try these:

- [simplediff](https://github.com/paulgb/simplediff)
- [PHP diff tool](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/8242-PHP-Compare-two-files-and-show-differences-in-Web-page.html)
- [PHP-FineDiff](https://github.com/gorhill/PHP-FineDiff)

Also, there are related StackOverflow questions:

- [Calculate text diffs in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112523/calculate-text-diffs-in-php)
- [Highlight the difference between two strings in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321294/highlight-the-difference-between-two-strings-in-php)

Please study the answers to them as well.